# Saving Chrome console log stuck on writing file

Tags: google-chrome

The problem happens after updating chrome to version 85.0.4183.121.

I was able to save console log by right clicking on the log, and then clicking `Save as` on the context menu and specify the file location.

After the update, There is a little progress bar labeled [Writing File...] on the header of the console region.  There would be no progree on the bar.  It's just stuck and the log file's size is 0.

If I repeatly trying to save the log file, there would be more progress bar show up on the console header.

[image: Writing file...]

Is there any way to save the console log?

Answer (score 1):

The saving of console log works again after upgrading chrome to version 86.0.4240.75.

I would say it's a bug from last version, no one should encounter this problem any more.  Mark this as solved.